# How to monitor Python scripts using Sensu?

Tags: python, monitoring, sensu

I would like to use Sensu Core to monitor python scripts and I am confused how to do it.

From Sensu documentation this requires [Sensu Checks](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/checks). In the provided example ruby script checks that chef-client is running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# get the current list of processes
processes = `ps aux`

# determine if the chef-client process is running
running = processes.lines.detect do |process|
  process.include?('chef-client')
end

# return appropriate check output and exit status code
if running
  puts 'OK - Chef client process is running'
  exit 0
else
  puts 'WARNING - Chef client process is NOT running'
  exit 1
end
```

How to implement such a check for a specific script and not the application? That is, how would I go about monitoring a specific python script (e.g. test.py) and not python in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have been running some python scripts in sensu for my AWS Linux clients successfully , this is a good example of my check definition:

```
{
 "checks": {
"check-rds-limit": {
  "interval": 86400, 
  "command": "/etc/sensu/plugins/rds-limit-check.py",
  "contacts": [
    "cloud-ops"
  ],
  "occurrences": 1,   
  "subscribers": [
    "cloud-ops-subscription"
  ], 
  "handlers": [
    "email",
    "slack"
  ]
}
  }
}
```

And your python plugin can start with defining the shebang path:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
...
...
//<code condition for warning>
sys.exit(1)
//<code condition for critical>
sys.exit(2)
//<code condition where everything is fine>
sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally the above script is searching for the string `chef-client` in the running processes. You could replace that with any other string, like `test.py`, which would detect if any program running has `test.py` in its name. (You might need to match the sub-string `test.py` if you run the program with `python test.py`, I don't know ruby.)

I would suggest that you use [Sensu process check plugin](https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-process-checks/blob/master/bin/check-process.rb) for a more general function which includes more customization. Look at the other [sensu plugins](https://github.com/sensu-plugins) too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not monitor the expected result or operation of the script rather than the process itself. Typically, we will setup checks to monitor an end point, in the case of a web application, or an observed behavior, such as messages in a database, to determine if the application is running.

There will be times when the *process* is technically running but not anything due to an error condition or resource issue. Monitoring the expected result is a much better option than watching a process.

Comment: Unfortunately the aim is to monitor long running services which do not "exit" unless there is an unexpected error

Comment: How will tell the difference between a wedged process, that is technically running and has a valid pid, and a process that is operating normally. The only way, that I am aware, is to measure the expected results of the long running process. This process should produce, a file, log entries or something as part of it processing, that can be measured.